# why sentry config in nest express app dose not show spans in doshboard?

Tags: nestjs, sentry

After I add Senty to nest app, 'http.server' span just added to the dashboard.
My config is:

```
 Sentry.init({
      dsn: configService.get('SENTRY_DSN'),
      tracesSampleRate: +configService.get('SENTRY_SAMPLE_RATE'),
      sampleRate: +configService.get('SENTRY_SAMPLE_RATE'),
      environment: configService.get('NODE_ENV'),
      debug: true,
      attachStacktrace: true,
      integrations: [
        new Sentry.Integrations.Http(),
        new Sentry.Integrations.Mysql(),
        new Sentry.Integrations.Modules(),
        new Sentry.Integrations.Express(),
      ],
    });

    app.use(
      Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler({
        ip: true,
        request: true,
        transaction: true,
        user: true,
      }),
    );
    app.use(Sentry.Handlers.tracingHandler());

...

  app.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());
```

and my packages are :

```
    "@sentry/node": "^7.58.0",
    "@sentry-internal/tracing": "7.58.0",
    "@sentry/core": "7.58.0",
    "@sentry/types": "7.58.0",
    "@sentry/utils": "7.58.0",
```

I need to get other spans in doshboard

Answer (score 1):

To add custom spans, you can use the `Sentry.startTransaction()` method to create a new transaction and then use the `Sentry.captureSpan()` method to capture individual spans within that transaction.

```
const transaction = Sentry.startTransaction();

const span = transaction.startChild({
  op: 'custom_operation',
  description: 'Description of the custom operation',
});

// Perform your custom operation here

span.finish();

transaction.finish();
```

Comment: but In Express all of these have been done automatically. Also in nestJs 8 NestExpressApp